# Looking For Working Example of ColorBox with 1 day Cookie Expire

Tags: jquery, cookies, colorbox

Using ColorBox jQuery Lightbox, i've almost got this working but it ONLY WORKS in I.E. and not FireFox... any ideas what i could fix to make this work in Firefox and other Mozilla browsers?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>Working ColorBox Example Using Cookie</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body{font:12px/1.2 Verdana, sans-serif; padding:0 10px;}
        a:link, a:visited{text-decoration:none; color:#416CE5; border-bottom:1px solid #416CE5;}
        h2{font-size:13px; margin:15px 0 0 0;}
    </style>
    <link media="screen" rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox.css" />
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="../colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
      <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') === -1) {
        var expires = new Date();
        expires.setDate(expires.getDate()+1); // +1 = in 1 day
        document.cookie = "visited=true; expires="+expires.toUTCString();

        // replace this with your actual call to colorbox.
        $.colorbox({html:"welcome!"});
    }
});
    </script>
Back Page
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Native code for creating a cookie is pretty simple, so I don't think I'd use a plugin for setting/reading a single cookie.  The colorbox FAQ has an entry on it: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/faq#faq-cookie

For you, it would look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') === -1) {
        var expires = new Date();
        expires.setDate(expires.getDate()+1); // +1 = in 1 day
        document.cookie = "visited=true; expires="+expires.toUTCString();

        // replace this with your actual call to colorbox.
        $.colorbox({html:"Welcome!"});
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey That almost works however it only works in I.E. and Not Firefox Mozilla... any ideas what i could change to make it work in Firefox?
I've modified the original post above with your cookie added.

Comment: Or... perhaps we need to create a Named Cookie that would not cause a FireFox issue? What is the best approach for doing this?

Comment: There isn't anything there that would be incompatible with FireFox.  I suggest clearing your cookies to make sure that isn't the issue, then checking your developer console (firebug) to see if something else is causing an error.

Comment: Yes, tested in FireFox(Firebug) ... did not see any initial issues.. 
Also I successfully cleared all Cookies, ran the the above html file with 1day cookie expire and here was the following results:
1)I.E. :Works successfully. Clearing Cookie allows testing.
2)FireFox: Works once and does not work again even after clearing the cookie... checked FireFox(Debug) no errors found
3)Google Chrome: Cookie never expires after 1 day... it just keeps coming up.
4)Safari: Works successfully. Clearing Cookie allows testing.

Comment: So far Still NOT Working... have tried almost everything... even debugging the cookie showed NO errors from what i could tell. 
The Issue appears that this is Not working in Fireworks even after i clear the cookie and refresh the browser.
Any help would be greatly appreciated... i still believe in this color box modal... but can't seem to get past this issue.
Eagerly wait for a solution from anyone. Also, can anyone else test this to see if they get the same issues?
Again, Works in I.E. but Not FireFox.